# Tough SQL problem for an amateur like me

Tags: sql

My family has several stock accounts, and I keep a table of stock values for their contents and enter current values daily.  Fields are...

```
  ACCOUNT / TICKER / QUANTITY / CLOSINGDATE/  CLOSING (current price)
```

To get a report of the current stock contents and most recent price, I am using this code.  I add this up row by row, and get an account total (for account # 2, for example ).  The table is designed this way also so I can track individual stock performance.

```
SELECT distinct ticker, account, closingdate, quantity, closing, (quantity*closing)  as "Net"
FROM "stock values" AS S
WHERE
(account=2) and
(quantity>0.000001) and
(closingdate =(SELECT  MAX(closingdate) FROM "stock values" WHERE ( ticker = S.ticker) and (account=s.account)) )
```

But now what I would like to do is create a report that looks like this on a TdbGrid so that... i get a report, grouped by account with the most recent distinct tickers added up FOR THAT ACCOUNT.  Four days later, I cannot crack this.

```
Account                  Value
      1                   35,000.00
      2                  122,132,32
      3                       43.23
```

I'm using Nexus 3 on Delphi 7.

Any help, greatly GREATLY appreciated.

Larry

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like you just have to add a `group by`:

```
select  account
,       sum(quantity*closing)
from    "stock_values" as S
where   s.closingdate = 
        (
        select  max(closingdate) 
        from    "stock values" as S2
        where   S2.ticker = S.ticker 
                and S2.account = S1.account
        )
group by
        account
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can have the same stock across multiple accounts, I would pre-query the last closing date per stock per account... This way, if you have stock in company "X" and entered its daily balance for Feb 4th to Account #1, but forgot to enter the "X" price for Account #5, you would have each account with different "Last Date Entered" for a particular stock.  It would actually be better to have two tables... one with nothing but your stocks, closing date and closing price.  Then join that to the accounts that use those stocks...  However, this query should get you a DETAILED breakdown per account showing all the maximum respective stock dates...  The next query will be simplified for totals per account... This one is primarily for a sanity check to ensure you're getting what you expect.  This does ALL the accounts, but you can adjust your WHERE clause to get only ONE specific account if you so need to.

```
SELECT 
      ticker, 
      account, 
      closingdate, 
      quantity, 
      closing, 
      (quantity*closing)  as "Net" 
   FROM 
      "stock values" AS S,
      ( select account,
               ticker, 
               max(closingdate) LastDatePerStock
            from 
               "stock values" sMax
            group by 
               account, ticker ) TickerDate
   WHERE 
          s.account = TickerDate.account
      and s.ticker = TickerDate.ticker
      and s.closingdate = TickerDate.LastDatePerStock
      and (quantity>0.000001)
   order by 
      account, 
      ticker
```

Now, the query simplified with just the account and the closing balance for all their stocks without seeing exactly what stocks are in the portfolio.

```
SELECT 
      account, 
      max( closingdate ) LatestClosingDate, 
      sum((quantity*closing))  as "Net" 
   FROM 
      "stock values" AS S,
      ( select account,
               ticker, 
               max(closingdate) LastDatePerStock
            from 
               "stock values" sMax
            group by 
               account, ticker ) TickerDate
   WHERE 
          s.account = TickerDate.account
      and s.ticker = TickerDate.ticker
      and s.closingdate = TickerDate.LastDatePerStock
      and (quantity>0.000001)
   group by 
      account
```